# data.table fast access to column by expression

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get a column from data.table by given expression. I receive `CaseID` as an expression. `expr_caseid <- expression(CaseID)`. **How do I get the column by expression in a fastest possible way?**

```
library(data.table)
dt_fcst <- data.table(CaseID = as.integer(runif(1e8)*100))

expr_caseid <- expression(CaseID)

testExpr = function(DT_, expr_){
    DT_[[deparse(substitute(expr_))]]
}

testGetElement = function(DT_, expr_){
    getElement(DT_, deparse(substitute(expr_)))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
##  by_char = dt_fcst[['CaseID']],
    by_deparse = testExpr(dt_fcst, CaseID),
##  by_expr = dt_fcst[, list(CaseID)],
##  by_dollar = dt_fcst$CaseID,
    by_eval = eval(
        expr_caseid, 
        envir = as.environment(dt_fcst)
    ),
    by_getElement = testGetElement(dt_fcst, CaseID)
#   ,by_index = dt_fcst@.Data[[1]]
, times = 1000L)
```

Results of performance measurements:

Unit: microseconds

```
          expr  min    lq    mean median   uq   max neval cld
    by_deparse 37.2 41.35 55.0700  46.15 60.6 357.8  1000   b
       by_eval 15.9 22.30 29.2194  24.80 34.3 289.8  1000  a 
 by_getElement 38.3 42.20 55.9087  47.30 63.2 283.3  1000   b
```

Comment: Don't coerce to `environment`; it works just fine as it is (as a `list`): `microbenchmark(
  ev  = eval(expr_caseid,envir = as.environment(dt_fcst)),
  ev2 = eval(expr_caseid,dt_fcst)
)`. I see it 4x as fast. Anyway, I'm curious why you would be doing this operation so many times that speed mattered...? Also, this doesn't seem very related to `data.table`.

Comment: @Frank I am doing huge amount simulations and write results to data.table on every iteration.  The table is updated by given expression for a column. I have marked with `data.table` tag, because I thought there is a fast way to do it though underlying `C++` structures to get it faster than I know from R. Thx for coercing advice, I have thought that `data.table` is an environment, than i would expect as in documentation of `as.environment`: *...If it is already an environment, just return it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with comment by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank)

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr  min    lq     mean median    uq     max neval cld
 by_evalNoCoerce  1.8  4.00   8.7652   5.30  7.60   479.8  1000  a 


microbenchmark(
##  by_char = dt_fcst[['CaseID']],
    by_deparse = testExpr(dt_fcst, CaseID),
##  by_expr = dt_fcst[, list(CaseID)],
##  by_dollar = dt_fcst$CaseID,
    by_eval = eval(
        expr_caseid, 
        envir = as.environment(dt_fcst)
    ),
    by_getElement = testGetElement(dt_fcst, CaseID),
    by_evalNoCoerce = eval(expr_caseid, dt_fcst)
#   ,by_index = dt_fcst@.Data[[1]]
, times = 1000L)
```